# Detecting a change in monitor refresh rate in c++

Tags: c++, windows

Is it possible to detect a change in the refresh rate of a monitor programmatically without having to poll for it constantly? This would likely be platform dependent so I am mainly interested in windows and android. I did some research on windows and found a callback for a change in resolution via the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message but I couldn't find one for a change in monitor refresh rate.

I also know of the `EnumDisplaySettings` function and its equivalent on other operating systems but as I said I would really like to avoid sticking a thread in a loop just to check whether the refresh rate has changed.

Comment: It might be useful do also say why you need that information. Because depending on that you might have different options.

Comment: @– t.niese Well I am making something like a video player. At the moment I am using vulkan to display the video frames. Vulkan synchronizes with the monitor refreshes though so playing for example a 30 fps video on a 144 hz monitor isn't really great. I kind of have to display one video frame every 4-5  actual window refreshes. That being said if for some reason the monitor refresh rate changes at some point everything falls apart. Of course there might be a better way to do this all together and if so I would love to know.

Comment: Have you actually checked that WM_DISPLAYCHANGE isn't sent on a timing change (even though that information isn't part of the wParam/lParam the window procedure receives)? I do agree there doesn't appear to be a 'normal' way to receive asynchronous notification of timing changes on Windows.

Comment: Why don’t you decide which video frame to display based on the elapsed time? Even if you know the refresh rate of the display you won’t know how many frames per seconds the hardware you are one is capable to send to the display.

Comment: @– SoronelHaetir I have not because the documentation says pretty much nothing about it. I suppose I can give it a try though just in case.

Comment: @– t.niese Basing it on the elapsed time (and not getting frame lag) is unfortunately not really possible because that would require an extremely precise timer and the only real timer that's available is thread sleeping and that just isn't accurate enough. And you would hardly see hardware that isn't capable of displaying a 1080p60 fps video these days. Otherwise you wouldn't even be able to watch youtube videos.

Comment: @ – SoronelHaetir ooookay. Well I made a tiny test with a   bare bones window and it actually seems to be sending a WM_DISPLAYCHANGE on refresh rate change. I would like to confirm this in the actual program I am making but it really seems like that's the case. Nice going on your docs microsoft !